# ¿Como buscar divisores con for ? java

Tags: java, bucle-for

Debo buscar todos los divisores de un número, en este caso yo elegí el número `18`. Intenté hacerlo pero me sale esto:

> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36 y 45

Cuando tendría que salir :

> 1, 2, 3, 6, 9 y 18

```
public class Divisor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numero = 18;
        int div=0;
        int contador=0;

        for(int i = 1 ; i <10 ; i++){
            if(numero%2==0){
                contador++;
                div+=contador;
            }
            else {
                contador++;
                div+=contador;
            }

        System.out.println(div);
        }
    }
}
```

Si alguien me puede decir en qué me equivoqué, se lo agradecería. :)

Comment: Lo puedes encontrar en este enlace: https://todoenlaluna.wordpress.com/2011/10/30/java-divisores-de-un-numero/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haber primero que nada tu codigo esta un poquito mal en esta instruccion

> if(numero%2==0){
>                   contador++;
>                   div+=contador;
>               }

lo que haces es ver si 18 es divisible entre 2 y luego aumentar un contador que no se el motivo de ello y sumarselo a div que te da resultados incorrectos, que no es lo que quieres... Lo que qieres es buscar los divisores de este. Ahora la solucion a tu problema para ver los divisores del 18 es la siguiente

Te lo explicare paso a paso

```
public class Divisor {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numero = 18; // pero te lo pueden entrar supongo que sabes como hacerlo
    //iteras desde 1 hasta el numero para encontrar los divisores
    for(int i = 1 ; i <=numero ; i++){
        if(numero%i==0){
            //imprimes la solucion
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Aqui tienes un codigo depurado y facil de entender... Espero que te sirva cualqier duda me dices. Salu2 ;)

Comment: hay 2 problemas con esta respuesta. Primero no le estas explicando como lo haces. Segundo, buscar divisores de un numero, hasta un numero mayor es algo que no sirve, ya que al pasar el numero ya ninguno es divisor. y despues, n es distinto que N...

Comment: tienes toda la razon no me fije....ahora lo arreglo estaba pensando en otra cosa

Comment: Explicale su error por favor... ;)

Comment: si la respuesta es la que querias por favor marcala como correcta gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Asi deberia funcionar sin problema, acordaos de importar el java.util para el scanner.

```
static void divisores(Scanner sc){
int num;

do{
System.out.println("Introduzca el numero a dividir:");
num=sc.nextInt();
}while(num<=0);

for (int i=1; i<=num; i++){
    if(num%i==0){
    System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tienes algunos tú código. Aquí tienes una solución partiendo de la tuya.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Divisor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero = 18;
        LinkedList<Integer> divisores = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= numero ; i++){
            if(numero % i == 0){
                divisores.add(i);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexRivas Para que se puede mantener un listado de todos los divisores del número y después, imprimirlo.